# assign multiple rolling sums at once with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, assign, cumulative-sum

I have a dataframe with counts in one column and I would like to assign several cumulative sums of this column at once. I tried the below code but unfortunately it gives me only the last cumulative sum for all columns.

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'counts':[242,99,2,13,0]})
kwargs = {f"cumulative_{i}" : lambda x: x['counts'].shift(1).rolling(i).sum() for i in range(1,4)}
d.assign(**kwargs)
```

this is what it gives me

```
counts  cumulative_1    cumulative_2    cumulative_3
0   242     NaN                NaN                 NaN
1   99      NaN                NaN                 NaN
2   2       NaN                NaN                 NaN
3   13      343.0              343.0               343.0
4   0       114.0              114.0               114.0
```

but I would like to get this

```
counts  cumulative_1    cumulative_2    cumulative_3
0   242     NaN                NaN                 NaN
1   99      242.0              NaN                 NaN
2   2       99.0               341.0               NaN
3   13      2.0                101.0               343.0
4   0       13.0               15.0                114.0
```

what can I change to get the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable `i` defined in the lambda has a global scope, and it's not captured in the lambda definition, i.e. it's always evaluated to `3`, the last value when the loop ends. In order to capture `i` at definition time, you can define a wrapper function that captures `i` for each iteration of the loop and returns the lambda that can infer the correct `i` from it's enclosing environment:

```
def roll_i(i):
    return lambda x: x['counts'].shift(1).rolling(i).sum()

kwargs = {f"cumulative_{i}" : roll_i(i) for i in range(1,4)}
d.assign(**kwargs)

   counts  cumulative_1  cumulative_2  cumulative_3
0     242           NaN           NaN           NaN
1      99         242.0           NaN           NaN
2       2          99.0         341.0           NaN
3      13           2.0         101.0         343.0
4       0          13.0          15.0         114.0
```